# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of plane reflection operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to calculate the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and matrix of a linear operator

$$ A:\Bbb R^3 \to\Bbb R^3$$

which is a reflection on the plane$ y=-x/2$.

I know that reflector transforms $(x,y,z)$ into $(x,y,-z)$ but I don't know how to deal with it when given a specific axes of symmetry.

Is it possible to know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors without calculating the operator matrix?

Comment: $x+2y=0$ describes a plane not a line. A normal to this plane is $(1,2,0)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A$ fixes the subspace $V$ of $\Bbb R^3$ given by
$$
V=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x+2y=0\}
$$
Since any vector in $V$ may be written as
$$
(-2y,y,z)=y(-2,1,0)+z(0,0,1)
$$
we see that $V=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{(-2,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. Since $A$ fixes $V$, it follows that $A(-2,1,0)=(-2,1,0)$ and $A(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)$. Hence $v_1=(-2,1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,0,1)$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$.

Next, note that the vector $(1,2,0)$ is orthogonal to the plane $V$. Since $A$ reflects vectors through the plane $V$, it follows that $A(1,2,0)=-(1,2,0)$. That is, $v_3=(1,2,0)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_2=-1$.

Comment: Note that these eigenvectors are exactly the eigenvectors of the matrix found in @samiBenRomdhane's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v_1=(-2,1,0), v_2=(-2,1,1)$ and $v_3=(1,2,0)$ so $B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ and the two former vectors span the plane $x+2y=0$ and the last vector is orthogonal to it. The matrix of the reflection $T$ in the basis $B$ is

$$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
and clearly that $1,1$ and $-1$ are the eigenvalues associated to the eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$ respectively. 
now let $P$ the change matrix from the standard basis $B_c$ to $B$ then
$$P=(v_1\;v_2\;v_3)$$
and then the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis is
$$[T]_{B_c}=P[T]_BP^{-1}=\frac15\begin{pmatrix}3&-4&0\\-4&-3&0\\0&0&5\end{pmatrix}$$